# LINQ Anonimous Type como parâmetro

Tags: c#, linq

Estou tentado criar um método que receba um tipo anônimo (consulta LINQ)

(Favor me corrijam se o termo `tipo anônimo (anonymous types)` estiver incorreto)

`MinhaLista (produtos.Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Estoque})`

Pedi para o Visual Studio criar o método automaticamente e me foi gerado:
`public static object MinhaLista (object @select)`

Gostaria que no método fosse possível fazer:

```
foreach (var produto in produtos)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(produto.Id);
            }
```

Qual a forma correta para definir um método para receber este `tipo anônimo (anonymous types)`?

Comment: Esta é uma forma, mas depende do que você quer fazer. Não sei se dá para responder isto só com esta informação.

Comment: Editei com o que eu gostaria de fazer no método. @bigown

Comment: Agora a pergunta ficou totalmente sem sentido.

Comment: Como eu poderia ter acesso aos dados passados por `MinhaLista (produtos.Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Estoque})` no meu método `MinhaLista (object @select) {}`

Comment: o seu método tem que ser anonymous mesmo?, não poderia criar uma classe que tivesse os tipos que você esta passando?

Comment: De acordo com sua pergunta, acredito que minha resposta seja a correta. Pois estou te mostrando como pegar propriedades de um objeto anônimo. Além disso ainda provo o funcionamento no fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro que você crie um *[Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx)* de `object` para isso, pois garantira o reuso, segue o código do extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static object GetPropriedade(this object obj, string propName)
    {
        if (obj== null)
            return null;
        PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
        if (prop != null)
           return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Depois é só chamar no objeto que possui a propriedade:

```
public void MostrarPropriedade(object obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetPropriedade("Id"));
}
```

Pode  ver um exemplo no meu Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JXqzAM

Answer (score 1):

No geral não é uma boa ideia tentar passar um tipo anônimo entre métodos.

O ideal neste caso é você criar um novo tipo para ser usado, como por exemplo

```
public class MeuProduto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Estoque{ get; set; }
}
```

Então você poderia mudar sua query para usar este tipo

```
MinhaLista (produtos.Select(p => new MeuProduto{Id = p.Id, Estoque = p.Estoque})
```

Depois disso você deve conseguir declarar sua função como

```
public static object MinhaLista (IEnumerable<MeuProduto> @select)
```

Comment: Embora eu siga seu conselho, não pude marcar como resposta seguindo o critério da pergunta. 

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Outra maneira que encontre foi utilizando `IEnumerable<dynamic>` (perde-se porém, a capacidade de intellisense para os atributos).

```
{
   MinhaLista (produtos.Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Estoque})
}

public static object MinhaLista (IEnumerable<dynamic> produtos)
{
    foreach (var produto in produtos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(produto.Id);
    }
    ....
}
```